# Font End secure authentication only allowed to come from a specific website

Tags: security, authentication, client-side

I have a private rest API. Each of our clients websites currently performs server side authentication over SSL to start an order with us. Each client has a unique client id so I can identify which client is making the request and reject any client id which doesn't exist in our system. Is there a way to do this securely from the front end of a clients website with javascript? I can't put the client id in the client code since any developer could look at the source code and figure out how to spoof requests from another site. I think checking referrer headers is not reliable as well? Would really like to know the best practice for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but typically you would encode your client id as a claim in the security token issued when authenticating your users. As the security token is signed by the issuer, you can verify that the token is not modified when you receive the token on each request.

Obviously you will need to use the https protocol to prevent the token from being stolen. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claims-based_identity) for more information.

Comment: This sounds like something you do on the server side. I'm looking for front end solutions. I have a working, encoded server side solution that is secure and works quite well already but I'm trying to turn out product into something that's more easily integrateable with third parties and with that am trying to eliminate the need for server side communication.

Comment: Indeed, you would do this when authenticating the user which already requires server communication. You cannot trust the client to do this as it would be easy to change in the browser.

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to authenticate users but only identify a website which is allowed to speak to my API.

Comment: > 'but only identify a website which is allowed to speak to my API'.    You cannot make any authorization decisions at the client side. Anything coming from the client is untrusted by default.